# How to upload more than 1 file, using Javascript to Amazon s3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Just struggling to upload two files at the same time using "file.upload". I've set up the function to upload the logoFile, however I'm not sure how to modify it to include the bannerFile at the same time? Any help is much appreciated. I have checked similar questions, but have failed to find any that replicate this.

```
module.exports = async function(req,res)  {
const venueName = req.body.venueName
const logoFile = req.file('logoImage')
const bannerFile = req.file('bannerImage')

const options =
{
    adapter: require('skipper-better-s3'),
    key: 'MY_KEY_KEY',
    secret: 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
    bucket: 'happyhour-images',
    s3params:
        { ACL: 'public-read'
        },
    onProgress: progress => sails.log.verbose('Upload progress:', progress)
}

logoFile.upload(options, async (err, files) => {
    if (err) { return res.serverError(err.toString()) }

    const fileUrl = files[0].extra.Location
    await Venue.create({
        venueName: venueName,
        logoImageUrl: fileUrl,
    }).fetch()

    res.redirect('/venues')
})
}
```

Comment: To upload multiple files at the same time, you would require multi threading/multiprocessing functionality. I'm quite sure that javascript does not support this. Why do you need to upload at the same time anyway?

Comment: Oh it doesn't have to be exactly the same time I guess. But the images are contained within the same form? Should I do it a different way?